# Evans Representation formula for solution of Poissons equation

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

In Evans PDE, Chapter 2 Theorem 9 we have:

Let $f \in C^2_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $n \geq 3$. Then any bounded solution of $$-\Delta u = f$$
in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has the form $$u(x)  = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \Phi(x-y)f(y)dy +C.$$

Then there's a remark: If $n=2$, $\Phi(x) = - \frac{1}{2 \pi} \log|x|$ is unbounded as $|x| \rightarrow \infty$, and so may be $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \Phi(x-y)f(y)dy. $

My question is: If $f$ has compact support then let the compact set $\overline{V}$ be the support of $f$.

Then the integral becomes  $\int_V \Phi(x-y)f(y)dy. $ Now since $\Phi f$ is continuous **away from zero** it achieves its $\max$ on $V$, so the integral is finite?

Meaning we shouldn't look at large values for $x$, because then we will be outside of $V$ in which case the integral will be zero.

What am I missing?

EDIT: see the comment by cmk which answers this.

Comment: Just because $\Phi(x-y)$ is looking at a limited range of $y$ values doesn't mean that it can't blow up in $x$. $$-\frac{1}{2\pi}\log(|x-y|)$$ blows up as $|x|\rightarrow\infty$ for any fixed $y$.

Comment: @cmk Thanks, I edited it.